# How I can divide this array into columns in R

Tags: r

I want to divide this array into different columns using the character "|" as a separator.

```
[-8.618643,41.141412]|[-8.618499,41.141376]|[-8.620326,41.14251]|[-8.622153,41.143815]|[-8.623953,41.144373]|[-8.62668,41.144778]|[-8.627373,41.144697]|[-8.630226,41.14521]|[-8.632746,41.14692]|[-8.631738,41.148225]|[-8.629938,41.150385]|[-8.62911,41.151213]|[-8.629128,41.15124]|[-8.628786,41.152203]|[-8.628687,41.152374]|[-8.628759,41.152518]|[-8.630838,41.15268]|[-8.632323,41.153022]|[-8.631144,41.154489]|[-8.630829,41.154507]|[-8.630829,41.154516]|[-8.630829,41.154498]|[-8.630838,41.154489]
```

I would like something like that separated in to different columns.

```
"[-8.618643,41.141412]" "[-8.618499,41.141376]" "[-8.620326,41.14251]" "[-8.622153,41.143815]" "[-8.623953,41.144373]" "[-8.62668,41.144778]" ...
```

That is to say, one coordinate for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `|` with `\n`, and then read the text.
In this example I used `data.table`'s `fread()` to do the reading of the lines, with `sep = ""` to read every line 'as is'.

```
library(data.table)

str = "[-8.618643,41.141412]|[-8.618499,41.141376]|[-8.620326,41.14251]|[-8.622153,41.143815]|[-8.623953,41.144373]|[-8.62668,41.144778]|[-8.627373,41.144697]|[-8.630226,41.14521]|[-8.632746,41.14692]|[-8.631738,41.148225]|[-8.629938,41.150385]|[-8.62911,41.151213]|[-8.629128,41.15124]|[-8.628786,41.152203]|[-8.628687,41.152374]|[-8.628759,41.152518]|[-8.630838,41.15268]|[-8.632323,41.153022]|[-8.631144,41.154489]|[-8.630829,41.154507]|[-8.630829,41.154516]|[-8.630829,41.154498]|[-8.630838,41.154489]"

data.table::fread(text = gsub( "\\|", "\n", str ), sep = "", header = FALSE )

#                       V1
# 1: [-8.618643,41.141412]
# 2: [-8.618499,41.141376]
# 3:  [-8.620326,41.14251]
# 4: [-8.622153,41.143815]
# 5: [-8.623953,41.144373]
# 6:  [-8.62668,41.144778]
# 7: [-8.627373,41.144697]
# 8:  [-8.630226,41.14521]
# 9:  [-8.632746,41.14692]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit` to separate string by "|":

```
s <- "[-8.618643,41.141412]|[-8.618499,41.141376]|[-8.620326,41.14251]|[-8.622153,41.143815]|[-8.623953,41.144373]|[-8.62668,41.144778]|[-8.627373,41.144697]|[-8.630226,41.14521]|[-8.632746,41.14692]|[-8.631738,41.148225]|[-8.629938,41.150385]|[-8.62911,41.151213]|[-8.629128,41.15124]|[-8.628786,41.152203]|[-8.628687,41.152374]|[-8.628759,41.152518]|[-8.630838,41.15268]|[-8.632323,41.153022]|[-8.631144,41.154489]|[-8.630829,41.154507]|[-8.630829,41.154516]|[-8.630829,41.154498]|[-8.630838,41.154489]"
v <- unlist(strsplit(s,split = "\\|"))
```